# FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\BooleanType' not found

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

Faced this problem today. Could not find the cause or even a solution online. I did a quick fix, not sure how this is going to affect me later. If anyone has a better solution, do share. Thanks.

Got this error while trying to list the users `FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\BooleanType' not found in ..vendor\sonata-project\doctrine-orm-admin-bundle\Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Filter\BooleanFilter.php`

What I did to fix it was to change 
`{#vendor\sonata-project\doctrine-orm-admin-bundle\Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Filter\BooleanFilter.php#}`
<strike>use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\BooleanType;</strike>
`use Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\BooleanType;`
`use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQueryInterface;`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using an **old** version of `AdminBundle` with a newer, **incompatible** version of the `CoreBundle`.

The `BooleanType` form-type among others has been moved from the `AdminBundle` to the `CoreBundle`.

**[This commit](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/commit/c185a870cbf8fdccda81dbbcea7e12148121262a)** introduced them in the CoreBundle 15 days ago.

Update **both** bundles to the latest versions to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using a dev-master version of the sonataadminbundle you should also use dev-master of all of sonata dependencies. the following [commit](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/commit/8709d5e4015761d985c6d4d29e4a9333ef6780c8) address the issue in the same way as you did. Hopefully in a new future this will be marked as a stable version.

Comment: This is bad practice to use master version of verndors instead of stable.

Comment: @Koc yes! perfectly agree. But that argument should be addressed to nadjetey instead of me, because like I said "if using a dev-master version of the sonataadminbundle (...)". I just brought consistency to all sonata bundles in his project

Comment: Sorry. This is very sad that sonata-guys breaks BC on each of last releases.

Comment: @Koc, Probably they will make a major version with this. Currently, I'm also using dev-master and didn't had to change a piece of code, as far as I can remember.